# Why is $x - \mu$ independent of $\mu$ when $\mu$ is Gaussian prior on Gaussian $x$?

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution

Consider the following multivariate normal model,

$$
\mathbf{x}_n \stackrel{\texttt{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}), \quad \boldsymbol{\mu} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_0, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_0).
$$

I can compute the posterior w.r.t. $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ as

$$
\boldsymbol{\mu} \mid \mathbf{X} \sim \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}_N, \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_N),
$$

for some values $\boldsymbol{\mu}_N$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_N$. (They do not matter.) However, to compute the posterior predictive, I must compute

$$
p(\hat{\mathbf{x}} \mid \mathbf{X}) = \int p(\hat{\mathbf{x}} \mid \boldsymbol{\mu}) p(\boldsymbol{\mu} \mid \mathbf{X})d\boldsymbol{\mu}.
$$

The standard argument---[see eq. 40 here](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf)---is to observe that $(\hat{\mathbf{x}} - \boldsymbol{\mu})$ is independent of $\boldsymbol{\mu}$, and therefore the distribution on $\hat{\mathbf{x}} = (\hat{\mathbf{x}} - \boldsymbol{\mu}) + \boldsymbol{\mu}$ is also Gaussian distributed. I follow everything assuming this is true; *however*, it is not obvious to me that $(\hat{\mathbf{x}} - \boldsymbol{\mu})$ and $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ are independent.

Why does this hold?

Comment: Hint: what is the distribution of $\hat x - \mu$?  Specifically, can you discern how it might depend on $\mu$?

Comment: It is Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0, \boldsymbol{\Sigma})$. Are you saying because that r.v. does not dependent on $\boldsymbol{\mu}$, i.e. does not show up in the PDF, etc. it is independent? Is that formal enough?

Comment: What definitions and characterizations of independence do you know?  It is a theorem that when a variable has a conditional density that does not vary with the conditioning variable, then the two are independent.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks.